# Apps script, spreadsheet and setNumberFormat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet I pull some numbers from Google Analytics via Apps script and the Analytics API.

One of the numbers is the bounce rate, which is returned in the format 42.380071394743425. I want to display this with two digits after the decimal point (and I need to add a percentage sign). I would like to do this via setNumberFormat.

However a [format token](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens) like "0.00", "#,##" etc. result in output like "4.238.007.139.4743.425" which is not at all what I want. I somewhat suspect a part of the problem might be that my document is in German, with a comma as decimal delimiter, and the number from the API returned has a decimal point (or I might be overlooking something simple, which is just as likely).

So, can I use setNumberFormat, and what format token do I have to use to turn "42.380071394743425" into "42,38%"?

I am using the build-in App service. I do not have problems with other types of KPIs, just percentage values like bounceRate.

```
 var viewId = "<myViewId>"
 var options = {};
 options['max-results']  = 1;
 metric = "ga:bounceRate"; // actually this is passed in as a function parameter
  
 // formatDate is a wrapper that calls Utilities.formatDate   
 var startDate = formatDate(pDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 var endDate = formatDate(pDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(viewId, startDate, endDate, metric, options);
 .....
 token = [];
 
  // format is passed in as a function parameter to fit the metric
  switch(format) {
    case("percentage"):
      token.push(["0.00%"]);
    break;      
    default:
      token.push(["0.00"]); // tried different options to no avail
    break; 
  }  

 sheet.getRange(<row>,<col>).setValue(report.rows).setNumberFormats(token);
```

As I said the code itself is working fine if the API returns unformatted numbers (so I don't think the problem is in the code), but I can't get the bounceRate to display the way I want.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using Spreadsheet v4 api or the built in SpreadsheetApp service? Do you have a snippet of code to show how you are currently doing this?

Comment: @SpencerEaston, I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Select `Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number formats...` and type `##.##"%"`.

Or you can set the number format by GAS the same way.

```
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
range.setNumberFormat('##.##"%"');
```

This is US locale based. You may change the format string according to your spreadsheet's locale(`File > Spreadsheet settings...`). As you can see in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats), *the format is dependant on the spreadsheet's locale*.

Comment: This did not solve my problem but helped me to confirm that this is indeed a language specific problem. If I apply your format to a number with the country-specific decimal delimiter I get the desired output, however if I apply that to the API result (with the standard "american" decimal delimiter) this seems to clash with the German language settings in the document.

Comment: Yes, it's US locale based. As far as the input sheet's locale is fixed, you can change the format string in GAS according to your locale and then there's no problem. As you can see in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats), *the format is dependant on the spreadsheet's locale*.

Comment: So you should write the code reponding to the specific locale. Either US or German, not both.